# How to read variables from a php file in bash

Tags: bash, php

How do I export variables from a PHP script in Bash?

I'm writing a Bash script to read database names from `config.php` files of each website, and then import the database from the backup repository.
I tried to use `source config.php` but it seems it doesn't recognize PHP variables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you give us examples of the php files you are wanting to read from?

Comment: Naturally "source config.php" gave you errors: it's a different language than bash. You would get similar errors with "source config.pl" or "source config.c" etc

Comment: It may be easiest to write PHP code to extract those variables in a format easily consumed from bash, but we will know once you post an example of what you want to read from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simplified version would be something as follows:

2 lines in `config.php`:

```
cat config.php
$variable1 = 'foo with bar';
$variable1 = 'foo2 with bar2';
```

Set Bash `$variable1` to last matching instance of `$variable1` in `config.php`, just in case it has been reset.  If you want to change it to the first match, simply change `tail -1` to `head -1` in the following code:

```
variable1="$(grep -oE '\$variable1 = .*;' config.php | tail -1 | sed 's/$variable1 = //g;s/;//g')"
```

Confirm Bash variable via `echo`:

```
echo "$variable1"
'foo2 with bar2'
```

Note that this will mostly work for strings.  There are many types of PHP variables that cannot be directly converted to Bash variables.  The code above will grab the last `$variable1` referenced in `config.php`.  Like I said, if that variable has been set multiple times, you can set to the first value or last value by toggling `head` or `tail` in the Bash command that sets the variable.

Comment: Hi... what is the purpose of the sed in this snippet ?

Comment: @MarcoZen it is to remove the literal `$variable1 = ` and then the trailing `;`. So you are setting the bash `$variable1` to `'foo2 with bar2'`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that ...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use the program that will "do one thing well" (Unix philosophy), in this case use PHP to parse PHP. You can do so from bash as follows:

```
variable1=$(php -r 'require("input.php"); echo $variable1;')
variable2=$(php -r 'require("input.php"); echo $variable2;')
```

You can test this with an input.php file like:

```
<?php
$variable1="hello";
$variable2="hello2";
?>
```

For an example where the php file has a return, instead see my answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1469387/766334.

Answer (score 1):

Building up on [@Poikilos's answer](/a/747009):

```bash
eval "$(
  php -r '
    require("config.php");
    foreach(get_defined_vars() as $name => $var)
      if (is_string($var))
        echo "php_", $name, "=", escapeshellarg($var), "\n";
  '
)"
```

Would define a `$php_varname` shell variable for each `$varname` string PHP variable.

Beware that PHP variables that contain NUL bytes trip `escapeshellargs()`.